# Is C# really slower than say C++?

Tags: c#, c++, performance

I've been wondering about this issue for a while now.

Of course there are things in C# that aren't optimized for speed, so using those objects or language tweaks (like LinQ) may cause the code to be slower.

But if you don't use any of those tweaks, but just compare the same pieces of code in C# and C++ (It's easy to translate one to another). Will it really be that much slower ?

I've seen comparisons that show that C# might be even faster in some cases, because in theory the JIT compiler should optimize the code in real time and get better results:

[Managed Or Unmanaged?](http://www.grimes.nildram.co.uk/dotnet/man_unman.htm)

We should remember that the JIT compiler compiles the code at real time, but that's a 1-time overhead, the same code (once reached and compiled) doesn't need to be compiled again at run time.

The GC doesn't add a lot of overhead either, unless you create and destroy thousands of objects (like using String instead of StringBuilder). And doing that in C++ would also be costly.

Another point that I want to bring up is the better communication between DLLs introduced in .Net. The .Net platform communicates much better than Managed COM based DLLs.

I don't see any inherent reason why the language should be slower, and I don't really think that C# is slower than C++ (both from experience and lack of a good explanation)..

So, will a piece of the same code written in C# will be slower than the same code in C++ ?
In if so, then WHY ?

Some other reference (Which talk about that a bit, but with no explanation about WHY):

[Why would you want to use C# if its slower than C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787375/why-would-you-want-to-use-c-if-its-slower-than-c)

Comment: Because C# is much easier to use than C++, especially when GUI is concerned

Comment: @Brain can u explain 'depends',i didn't get it?

Comment: Really... It depends... Some things are faster, some are slower. C/C++ is more "deterministic" (no garbage collector at your back). If you want to spawn 100 threads I can tell you that the GC will haunt you with his slowness (and before telling me that 100 threads are too many, know that Skype and the McAfee AV are each at 40 threads now on my PC)... Marshaling in C# is a pain (and it's slower). Coding is quite fast. No, this isn't a flame. I truly prefer C#.

Comment: I think this should be edited and reopened.  I think the question asker might not understand that a more fundamental question impacts performance differences between C# and languages like C or C++, which would be "What's the difference between code generated (and how it's executed) by a C compiler and code generated by the C# compiler?"  C#/Java and other interpreted or VM languages may have several intermediary steps when running their bytecode that are totally absent in an equivalent C program.

Comment: If you want a real example, recently I had to port a quite big C++ algorithm to C#. I did it line by line, translating c++ constructs/structures to C# equivalent (e.g. map --> sortedlist etc.). Well, although I expected c++ to be faster, it wasn't. C# was slightly faster, but I can say that basically performances were the same. (And BTW C++ project was well written, no memory leaks etc...). So, C/C++ faster than C# is not an absolute truth...

Comment: While you *could* argue that (as stated) this qualifies as "not a real question", claiming it's subjective is nonsensical. "Is A faster than B" is something that's open to objective measurement. Even if the answer obtained by such measurement is ambiguous (some things are faster in one, some in the other), it's still objective.

Comment: @Jerry: I agree with you, and so I voted for reopening the topic!

Comment: I do know about the intermediate code. That's why I didn't ask about that.

Comment: There's been a great deal of discussion about this topic, and a lot of misguiding answers as well. So I thought to ask it here and see what we come up with :) ... I'm happy to see it stayed open.

Comment: See [the computer language benchmark game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/) for a thorough comparison of many languages on many different types of problems.

Comment: Using C++ will not automatically yield a faster program. C++ gives you much better control over the performance characteristics of your program thus enabling you to write a faster program, but it can be a lot of work.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Warning: The question you've asked is really pretty complex -- probably much more so than you realize. As a result, this is a *really* long answer.

From a purely theoretical viewpoint, there's probably a simple answer to this: there's (probably) nothing about C# that truly prevents it from being as fast as C++. Despite the theory, however, there are some practical reasons that it *is* slower at some things under some circumstances.

I'll consider three basic areas of differences: language features, virtual machine execution, and garbage collection. The latter two often go together, but can be independent, so I'll look at them separately.

### Language Features

C++ places a great deal of emphasis on templates, and features in the template system that are largely intended to allow as much as possible to be done at compile time, so from the viewpoint of the program, they're "static." Template meta-programming allows completely arbitrary computations to be carried out at compile time (I.e., the template system is Turing complete). As such, essentially anything that doesn't depend on input from the user can be computed at compile time, so at runtime it's simply a constant. Input to this can, however, include things like type information, so a great deal of what you'd do via reflection at runtime in C# is normally done at compile time via template metaprogramming in C++. There is definitely a trade-off between runtime speed and versatility though -- what templates can do, they do statically, but they simply can't do everything reflection can.

The differences in language features mean that almost any attempt at comparing the two languages simply by transliterating some C# into C++ (or vice versa) is likely to produce results somewhere between meaningless and misleading (and the same would be true for most other pairs of languages as well). The simple fact is that for anything larger than a couple lines of code or so, almost nobody is at all likely to use the languages the same way (or close enough to the same way) that such a comparison tells you anything about how those languages work in real life.

### Virtual Machine

Like almost any reasonably modern VM, Microsoft's for .NET can and will do JIT (aka "dynamic") compilation. This represents a number of trade-offs though.

Primarily, optimizing code (like most other optimization problems) is largely an NP-complete problem. For anything but a truly trivial/toy program, you're pretty nearly guaranteed you won't truly "optimize" the result (i.e., you won't find the true optimum) -- the optimizer will simply make the code *better* than it was previously. Quite a few optimizations that are well known, however, take a substantial amount of time (and, often, memory) to execute. With a JIT compiler, the user is waiting while the compiler runs. Most of the more expensive optimization techniques are ruled out. Static compilation has two advantages: first of all, if it's slow (e.g., building a large system) it's typically carried out on a server, and *nobody* spends time waiting for it. Second, an executable can be generated *once*, and used many times by many people. The first minimizes the cost of optimization; the second amortizes the much smaller cost over a much larger number of executions.

As mentioned in the original question (and many other web sites) JIT compilation does have the possibility of greater awareness of the target environment, which should (at least theoretically) offset this advantage. There's no question that this factor can offset at least part of the disadvantage of static compilation. For a few rather specific types of code and target environments, it *can* even outweigh the advantages of static compilation, sometimes fairly dramatically. At least in my testing and experience, however, this is fairly unusual. Target dependent optimizations mostly seem to either make fairly small differences, or can only be applied (automatically, anyway) to fairly specific types of problems. Obvious times this would happen would be if you were running a relatively old program on a modern machine. An old program written in C++ would probably have been compiled to 32-bit code, and would continue to use 32-bit code even on a modern 64-bit processor. A program written in C# would have been compiled to byte code, which the VM would then compile to 64-bit machine code. If this program derived a substantial benefit from running as 64-bit code, that could give a substantial advantage. For a short time when 64-bit processors were fairly new, this happened a fair amount. Recent code that's likely to benefit from a 64-bit processor will usually be available compiled statically into 64-bit code though.

Using a VM also has a possibility of improving cache usage. Instructions for a VM are often more compact than native machine instructions. More of them can fit into a given amount of cache memory, so you stand a better chance of any given code being in cache when needed. This can help keep interpreted execution of VM code more competitive (in terms of speed) than most people would initially expect -- you can execute a *lot* of instructions on a modern CPU in the time taken by *one* cache miss.

It's also worth mentioning that this factor isn't *necessarily* different between the two at all. There's nothing preventing (for example) a C++ compiler from producing output intended to run on a virtual machine (with or without JIT). In fact, Microsoft's C++/CLI is *nearly* that -- an (almost) conforming C++ compiler (albeit, with a lot of extensions) that produces output intended to run on a virtual machine.

The reverse is also true: Microsoft now has .NET Native, which compiles C# (or VB.NET) code to a native executable. This gives performance that's generally much more like C++, but retains the features of C#/VB (e.g., C# compiled to native code still supports reflection). If you have performance intensive C# code, this may be helpful.

### Garbage Collection

From what I've seen, I'd say garbage collection is the poorest-understood of these three factors. Just for an obvious example, the question here mentions: "GC doesn't add a lot of overhead either, unless you create and destroy thousands of objects [...]". In reality, if you create *and* destroy thousands of objects, the overhead from garbage collection will generally be fairly low. .NET uses a generational scavenger, which is a variety of copying collector. The garbage collector works by starting from "places" (e.g., registers and execution stack) that pointers/references are *known* to be accessible. It then "chases" those pointers to objects that have been allocated on the heap. It examines those objects for further pointers/references, until it has followed all of them to the ends of any chains, and found all the objects that are (at least potentially) accessible. In the next step, it takes all of the objects that are (or at least *might be*) in use, and compacts the heap by copying all of them into a contiguous chunk at one end of the memory being managed in the heap. The rest of the memory is then free (modulo finalizers having to be run, but at least in well-written code, they're rare enough that I'll ignore them for the moment).

What this means is that if you create *and destroy* lots of objects, garbage collection adds very little overhead. The time taken by a garbage collection cycle depends almost entirely on the number of objects that have been created but *not* destroyed. The primary consequence of creating and destroying objects in a hurry is simply that the GC has to run  more often, but each cycle will still be fast. If you create objects and *don't* destroy them, the GC will run more often *and* each cycle will be substantially slower as it spends more time chasing pointers to potentially-live objects, *and* it spends more time copying objects that are still in use.

To combat this, generational scavenging works on the assumption that objects that *have* remained "alive" for quite a while are likely to continue remaining alive for quite a while longer. Based on this, it has a system where objects that survive some number of garbage collection cycles get "tenured", and the garbage collector starts to simply assume they're still in use, so instead of copying them at every cycle, it simply leaves them alone. This is a valid assumption often enough that generational scavenging typically has considerably lower overhead than most other forms of GC.

"Manual" memory management is often just as poorly understood. Just for one example, many attempts at comparison assume that all manual memory management follows one specific model as well (e.g., best-fit allocation). This is often little (if any) closer to reality than many peoples' beliefs about garbage collection (e.g., the widespread assumption that it's normally done using reference counting).

Given the variety of strategies for both garbage collection *and* manual memory management, it's quite difficult to compare the two in terms of overall speed. Attempting to compare the speed of allocating and/or freeing memory (by itself) is pretty nearly guaranteed to produce results that are meaningless at best, and outright misleading at worst.

### Bonus Topic: Benchmarks

Since quite a few blogs, web sites, magazine articles, etc., claim to provide "objective" evidence in one direction or another, I'll put in my two-cents worth on that subject as well.

Most of these benchmarks are a bit like teenagers deciding to race their cars, and whoever wins gets to keep both cars. The web sites differ in one crucial way though: they guy who's publishing the benchmark gets to drive both cars. By some strange chance, his car always wins, and everybody else has to settle for "trust me, I was *really* driving your car as fast as it would go."

It's easy to write a poor benchmark that produces results that mean next to nothing. Almost anybody with anywhere close to the skill necessary to design a benchmark that produces anything meaningful, also has the skill to produce one that will give the results he's decided he wants. In fact it's probably *easier* to write code to produce a specific result than code that will really produce meaningful results.

As my friend James Kanze put it, "never trust a benchmark you didn't falsify yourself."

### Conclusion

There is no simple answer. I'm reasonably certain that I could flip a coin to choose the winner, then pick a number between (say) 1 and 20 for the percentage it would win by, and write some code that would look like a reasonable and fair benchmark, and produced that foregone conclusion (at least on some target processor--a different processor might change the percentage a bit).

As others have pointed out, for *most* code, speed is almost irrelevant. The corollary to that (which is much more often ignored) is that in the little code where speed does matter, it usually matters a *lot*. At least in my experience, for the code where it really does matter, C++ is almost always the winner. There are definitely factors that favor C#, but in practice they seem to be outweighed by factors that favor C++. You can certainly find benchmarks that will indicate the outcome of your choice, but when you write real code, you can almost always make it faster in C++ than in C#. It might (or might not) take more skill and/or effort to write, but it's virtually always possible.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer

Comment: At a previous company, a few of our decisions were based on benchmarking, but the benchmarking was poorly done because it missed the bigger picture (e.g. impact on the GC) or was just badly done.  Beware benchmarking... it's tempting to make decisions based on stuff done out of context.  If you do benchmark, then try to make it as representative as possible :)

Comment: IIRC, .NET runtime never interpret but always JIT. The optimization is done by both compiler at compile time (source code to IL) and jitter at runtime (IL to native instructions). The jitter may choose not to optimize if a method will take too long to jit. If complete optimization is required, you can use NGen to generate native image at installation time.

Comment: I think the answer is quite simple actually: my answer would be, "Yes, because C# practically forces you to make data structures reference types, which adds a new layer of indirection with every layer of wrapping, increasing memory traffic and reducing memory locality. In C++, no matter how many layers of wrapping you put around an object, the object will stay in the same location in memory." Do you agree?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes and no. From a practical viewpoint, yes, that's likely to weigh in favor of C++ more often than not. At the same time, GC can make it easy to just pass references around to avoid copying data in many cases.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yeah though my counterargument to that is, the GC only makes things slightly easier than using `shared_ptr` in C++ (or `swap`/`move` when needed), whereas it's *practically impossible* in C# to avoid adding extra layers of indirection: if you want to avoid copying, you *have* to make your type a reference type, which means you'll *never* be able to avoid an extra layer of indirection in all code that uses your type. By contrast, C++ lets you do things like using `make_shared`, which remove extra indirections as much as possible, or at least makes them cache-friendly.

Comment: @Mehrdad: All true...but keep in mind that in multithreaded code, `shared_ptr` requires atomic increment/decrement, which is also pretty slow as a rule. GC avoids that, so for some cases it can be a fairly big win.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Yeah it avoids atomic increment/decrement, but it now traverses the entire generation of objects instead. I suppose it *can* be a win but it's a *much* rarer scenario than the other cases. (Your program has to be multithreaded *and* it needs to have multithreaded `shared_ptr` access *and* `shared_ptr`'s bookkeeping needs to be your bottleneck, which seems kinda rare...)

Comment: @Mehrdad: That's one of the problems: you *don't* actually have to use the shared_ptr across threads -- if it's written to *allow* it, you're stuck with the atomic accesses, even if you never actually use the capability.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I guess, but isn't it pretty easy to copy Boost's `shared_ptr` and make your own `shared_ptr2` class (or whatever) that uses almost the same thing but with `BOOST_SP_DISABLE_THREADS` set to `1`? It seems like a pretty easy problem to solve... nowhere nearly as difficult as avoiding the GC in C#.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yup -- that's the sort of thing I was thinking of what I said: "you can almost always make it faster in C++ than in C#. It might (or might not) take more skill and/or effort to write, but it's virtually always possible."

Comment: And old thread but still interesting: I though about the whole memory/GC issues and one thing was interesting: malloc and free are kernel functions, right ? So calling them means at least two context switches while a GC can free memory only "virtually" (keep the memory for later allocations). Isn't this alone a reason that GC _can_ be faster when manual management is done naively ? In multicore systems a kernel context switch is quite expensive, I would argue that manual management must be done really carefully to achieve good performance for lots of allocations.

Comment: @Kr0e: no, `malloc` and `free` aren't (normally) kernel functions. Typically, `malloc` will occasionally allocate a big block of memory from the OS, and calling `malloc` will give pieces of that. If you allocate a *huge* chunk of memory at once, that'll often be passed through to the OS though.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Thx, obviously I did get this wrong in my last CS course. I was wondering the whole time why the hell malloc is still used so often when it introduces kernel calls.

Comment: @JerryCoffin do you have a couple of good books you recommend on the topic? I'm working on a scientific project written in C# and wonder if rewriting our algorithm in C++ rather than C# would make sense, or If I should better focus on optimizing the current code by learning more about how the internals works with the C# interpreter and JIT compiler

Comment: char *conclusion = "Tl;dr";

Comment: actually garbage collection makes huge impact on the performance. we are trying to get published an article and it contains the effect of the garbage collection a real crawler software :)

Comment: Nice answer, informative, but biased toward C#, the simple answer, is C# highly slower than C and C++ for 99% for the sake of all practical reasons.

Answer (score 43):

Because you don't always need to use the (and I use this loosely) "fastest" language?  I don't drive to work in a Ferrari just because it's faster...

Comment: I think this analogy is very apt. If I drove a Ferrari to work, I wouldn't get to work any faster. The car is certainly capable of going faster than what I drive, but the vehicle's capability isn't the limiting factor. There are speed limits, traffic, road conditions, etc. Similarly, software is usually bound by things such as user interaction, I/O, etc. What language you use won't make much difference in such cases.

Comment: Well, but the question was "Which of the cars is a Ferrari, and which is Volkswagen?" or if both are Ferrari or not.

Comment: @pepr The question in the heading is that yes, but the question at the end of the post is "why would you want to use a Volkswagen when you can use a Ferrari?".

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Yes. The answer can be similar -- "cost matters".

Comment: No, I ride to work on a motorcycle mostly because it is faster.

Comment: @CashCow Yeah, because your motorcycle can fit between traffic, which is the **correct choice for the situation**. A Ferrari, which for arguments sake we shall say is faster given no traffic, would be the wrong choice because it would not be effective in traffic. People should care less about the on-paper credentials of something (as it isn't Top Trumps) and more about the applicability of technology for a problem domain, as your analogy can demonstrate.

Comment: @FredLarson, answer owner, pepr... Simply your analogy is incorrect! Traffic in a processor is time based not computation based. Scheduling for a CPU in time based not computation based. CPU will be given to a process in a **limited TIME**. so if a process has less overall work, it is better. Faster language means less overall code line (overall works to be done). **In this case a Ferrari is actually a better choice**.

Comment: .NET can also do ahead-of-time (AoT) compilation

Answer (score 27):

Circa 2005 two MS performance experts from both sides of the native/managed fence tried to answer the same question. Their method and process are still fascinating and the conclusions still hold today - and I'm not aware of any better attempt to give an informed answer.  They noted that a discussion of *potential reasons* for differences in performance is hypothetical and futile, and a true discussion must have some *empirical basis* for the real world impact of such differences.

So, the [Old New Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/), and [Rico Mariani](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ricom/) set rules for a friendly competition. A Chinese/English dictionary was chosen as a toy application context: simple enough to be coded as a hobby side-project, yet complex enough to demonstrate non trivial data usage patterns.   The rules started simple - Raymond coded a straightforward C++ implementation, Rico migrated it to C# *line by line*, with no sophistication whatsoever, and both implementations ran a benchmark. Afterwards, several iterations of optimizations ensued.

The full details are here: [1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050509-30/?p=35683), [2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050510-55/?p=35673), [3](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050511-46/?p=35663), [4](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/11/416430.aspx), [5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-chineseenglish-dictionary-reader), [6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-first-cut), [7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-second-cut), [8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-third-cut), [9](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-fourth-cut), [10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-analyzing-the-managed-code), [11](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-the-fifth-cut-goes-foul), [12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-optimizing-the-managed-version), [13](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-sixth-cut), [14](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-conclusion-studying-the-space).

This dialogue of titans is exceptionally educational and I whole heartily recommend to dive in - but if you lack the time or patience, Jeff Atwood [compiled the bottom lines beautifully](http://blog.codinghorror.com/on-managed-code-performance-again/):

[image]

Eventually, C++ was 2x faster - but **initially, it was 13x slower.**

As Rico [sums up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ricom/performance-quiz-6-looking-at-the-sixth-cut):

> So am I ashamed by my crushing defeat? Hardly. The managed code
>   achieved a very good result for hardly any effort. To defeat the
>   managed version, Raymond had to:
>
> - Write his own file/io stuff
> - Write his own string class
> - Write his own allocator
> - Write his own international mapping
>
> Of course he used available lower level libraries to do this,
>   but that's still a lot of work. Can you call what's left an STL
>   program? I don't think so.

That is my experience still, 11 years and who knows how many C#/C++ versions later.

That is no coincidence, of course, as these two languages spectacularly achieve their vastly different design goals. C# wants to be used where development cost is the main consideration (still the majority of software), and C++ shines where you'd save no expenses to squeeze every last ounce of performance out of your machine: games, algo-trading, data-centers, etc.

Comment: This is the best answer, and he summarizes beautifully!

Answer (score 23):

C++ always have an edge for the performance. With C#, I don't get to handle memory and I have literally tons of resources available for me to do my job.

What you need to question yourself is more about which one saves you time. Machines are incredibly powerful now and most of your code should be done in a language that allows you to get the most value in the least amount of time.

If there is a core processing that takes way too long in C#, you could then build a C++ and interop your way to it with C#.

Stop thinking about your code performance. Start building value.

Comment: +1 for *"Stop thinking about your code performance. Start building value."*

Comment: I agree about the speed of development in C#. It's much more valuable in a lot of cases.

Comment: Developer needs a good choice for each cases. In some cases C# will not match needs. Assume a computation based application such as **Video Converter or Video Mixer or 3D virtualisation or Flow Computation or a game**. Also you must note to project target hardware. Some application must be run on a low-end HW.

Answer (score 7):

C# *is* faster than C++. Faster to write. For execution times, nothing beats a profiler.

But C# does not have as much libraries as C++ can interface easily.

And C# depends heavily on windows...

Comment: C# requires a lot more support from the compiler, OS and platforms.  A HUGE concern for embedded systems.

Comment: C# runs not just on Windows, but Mac, Linux, Android, iOS, ... see http://www.microsoft.com/net/multiple-platform-support, http://xamarin.com/platform, http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms.

Comment: @yoyo: C# does run on other platforms (and there was Mono under Linux also), but the libraries you may want to use (eg. Windows Forms) may not. Portability is a problem for C# development.

Comment: this answer has now changed. the .NET Standard runtime is currenly officially supported to run on Linux by Microsoft. So unless you have to develop on microcontrollers, portability is not an issue at all. Not to mention that it got a lot faster too.

Answer (score 6):

BTW, time critical applications are not coded in C# or Java, primarily due to uncertainty of when the Garbage Collection will be performed.

In modern times, application or execution speed is not as important as was previously.  Development schedules, correctness and robustness are higher priorities.  A high speed version of an application is no good if it has lots of bugs, crashes a lot or worse, misses an opportunity to get to market or be deployed.

Since development schedules are a priority, new languages are coming out that speed up development.  C# is one of these.  C# also assists in correctness and robustness by removing features from C++ that cause common problems:  one example is pointers.

The differences in execution speed of an application developed with C# and one developed using C++ is negligible on most platforms.  This is due to the fact that the execution bottlenecks are not language dependent but usually depend on the operating system or I/O.  For example if C++ performs a function in 5 ms but C# uses 2ms, and waiting for data takes 2 seconds, the time spent in the function is insignificant compared to the time waiting for data.

Choose a language that is best suited for the developers, platform and projects.  Work towards the goals of correctness, robustness and deployment.  The speed of an application should be treated as a bug:  prioritize it, compare to other bugs, and fix as necessary.

Comment: My understanding is that C# (Java too?) doesn't 'remove' the existence/concept of pointers so much as hide them from the programmer by an abstraction of sorts via the actual syntax.  This is a fairly inconsequential point though. The relative simplicity of C# is indisputable.

Answer (score 3):

A better way to look at it everything is slower than C/C++ because it abstracts away rather than following the stick and mud paradigm. It's called systems programming for a reason, you program against the grain or bare metal. Doing so also grants you speed you cannot achieve with other languages like C# or Java. But alas C roots are all about doing things the hard way, so your mostly going to be writing more code and spending more time debugging it.

C is also case sensitive, also objects in C++ also follow strict rule sets. Example a purple ice cream cone may not be the same as a blue ice cream cone, though they might be cones they may not necessarily belong to the cone family and if you forget to define what cone is you bug out. Thus the properties of ice cream may or may not be clones. Now the speed argument, C/C++ uses the stack and heap approach this is where bare metal gets it's metal.

With the boost library you can achieve incredible speeds unfortunately most game studios stick to the standard library. The other reason for this might be because software written in C/C++ tends to be massive in file size, as it's a giant collection of files instead of a single file. Also take note all operating systems are written in C so generally why must we ask the question what could be faster?!

Also caching is not faster than pure memory management, sorry but this just doesn't fan out. Memory is something physical, caching is something software does in order to gain a kick in performance. One could also reason that without physical memory caching would simply not exist. It doesn't void the fact memory must be managed at some level whether its automated or manual.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you write a small application that doesn't require much in the way of optimization in C++, if there is a faster route(C#)?

Comment: Why? Because I'm a sucker for seeing when my code runs. Including destructors. Even a small application benefits from being optimized for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Getting an exact answer to your question is not really possible unless you perform benchmarks on specific systems. However, it is still interesting to think about some fundamental differences between programming languages like C# and C++.

**Compilation**

Executing C# code requires an additional step where the code is JIT'ed. With regard to performance that will be in favor of C++. Also, the JIT compiler is only able to optimize the generated code within the unit of code that is JIT'ed (e.g. a method) while a C++ compiler can optimize across method calls using more aggressive techniques.

However, The JIT compiler is able to optimize the generated machine code to closely match the underlying hardware enabling it to take advantage of additional hardware features if they exist. To my knowledge the .NET JIT compiler doesn't do that but it would conceiveably be able to generate different code for Atom as opposed to Pentium CPU's.

**Memory access**

The garbage collected architecture can in many cases create more optimal memory access patterns than standard C++ code. If the memory area used for the first generation is small enough in can stay within the CPU cache increasing performance. If you create and destroy a lot of small objects the overhead of maintaing the managed heap may be smaller than what is required by the C++ runtime. Again, this is highly dependent on the application. [A study Python of performance](http://www.smallshire.org.uk/sufficientlysmall/2009/05/22/ironpython-hammers-cpython-when-not-mutating-class-attributes/) demonstrates that a specific managed Python application is able to scale much better than the compiled version as a result of more optimal memory access patterns.

Comment: There's an extra step for the JIT to compile the code, but because of the rule of re-use you'll probably use that piece of code 10000s of times more than that single compilation. (example: loops). So there's a question if the JIT did a good enough job to compinsate for that intial compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't let confusing!

- If a C# application is written in the best case and a C++ application is written in the best case, the C++ is faster.
  Many reason is here about why C++ is faster that C# inherently, such as C# uses virtual machine similar to JVM in Java. Basically higher level language has less performance (if uses in best case).
- If you're an experienced professional C# programmer just like you're an experienced professional C++ programmer, developing an application using C# is much more easy and fast than C++.

Many other situations between these situations is possible. For example, you can write an C# application and C++ application so that C# app runs faster than C++ one.

For choosing a language you should note the circumstances of the project and its subject. For a general business project you should use C#. For a hight performance required project like a Video Converter or Image Processing project you should choose C++.

### Update:

OK. Lets compare some practical reason about why most possible speed of C++ is more than C#. Consider a good written C# application and same C++ version:

- C# uses a VM as a middle layer for executing the application. It has overhead.
- AFAIK CLR could not optimises all C# codes in target machine. C++ application could be compiled on target machine with most optimisation.
- In C# the most possible optimisation for runtime means most possible fast VM. VM has overhead anyway.
- C# is a higher level language thus it generates more program code lines for the final process. (consider difference between an Assembly application and Ruby one! same condition is between C++ and a higher level language such as C#/Java)

If you prefer to get some more info in practice as an expert, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/145559/1074799). It is about Java but it also applies to C#.

Answer (score 0):

The primary concern would not be speed, but stability across windows versions and upgrades.  Win32 is mostly immune across windows versions making it highly stable.

When servers are decommissioned and software migrated, A lot of anxiety happens around anything using .Net and usually a lot of panic about .net versions but a Win32 application built 10 years ago just keeps running like nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I have been specializing in optimization for about 15 years, and regularly re write C++ code, making heavy use of compiler intrinsics as much as possible because C++ performance is often nowhere near what the CPU is capable of. Cache performance often needs to be considered. Many vector maths instructions are required to replace the standard C++ floating point code. 
A great deal of STL code is re written and often runs many times faster. Maths and code which makes heavy use of data can be re written with spectacular results, as the CPU approaches its optimum performance.

None of this is possible in C#. To compare their relative #real time# performance is really a staggeringly ignorant question. The fastest piece of code in C++ will be when each single assembler instruction is optimised for the task in hand, with no unnecessary instructions - at all. Where each piece of memory is used when it is required, and not copied n times because that’s what the language design requires. Where each required memory movement works in harmony with the cache.
Where the final algorithm cannot be improved, based on the exact real time requirements, considering accuracy and functionality.

Then you will be approaching an optimal solution.

To compare C# with this ideal situation is staggering. C# can’t compete. In fact, I am currently re writing a whole bunch of C# code (when I say re writing I mean removing and replacing it completely) because it is not even in the same city, let alone ball park when it comes to heavy lifting real time performance.

So please, stop fooling yourselves. C# is slow. Dead slow. All software is slowing down, and C# is making this speed decline worse. All software runs using the fetch execute cycle in assembler (you know – on the CPU). You use 10 times as many instructions; it’s going to go 10 times as slow. You cripple the cache; it’s going to go even slower. You add garbage collect to a real time piece of software then you are often fooled into thinking that the code runs ‘ok’ there are just those few moments every now and then when the code goes ‘a bit slow for a while’.

Try adding a garbage collection system to code where every cycle counts. I wonder if the stock market trading software has garbage collection (you know – on the system running on the new undersea cable which cost $300 million?). Can we spare 300 milliseconds every 2 seconds? What about flight control software on the space shuttle – is GC ok there? How about engine management software in performance vehicles? (Where victory in a season can be worth millions).

Garbage collection in real time is a complete failure.

So no, emphatically, C++ is much faster. C# is a leap backwards.

Comment: C# is not a leap backwards, because C# was designed with a completely different set of requirements than C++. C# trades speed of execution for speed of development. All those examples where you pointed out C# would fail (space shuttles, engine management etc.) were never target applications of C#. C# allows to deliver the completed product relatively fast. C# allows the product to run on any hardware that its virtual machine runs on. Can you write assembly optimizations, knowing that your code needs to run on hundred different hardware configurations?

Comment: I agree with what you say mag_zbc, but the original question was "Is C# really slower than say C++?"

And my 'leap backwards' comment was in reference to the speed of C#, not it's portability.

Comment: This is a biased view, which is based on pure speculative assumptions without providing any benchmarks.