# Writing performance critical C# code in C++

Tags: c#, c++, performance

I'm currently working on some performance critical code, and I have a particular situation where I'd love to write the whole application in C#, but performance reasons mean C++ ends up being FAR faster.

I did some benchmarking on two different implementations of some code (One in C#, another in C++) and the timings showed that the C++ version was 8 times faster, both versions in release mode and with all optimizations enabled. (Actually, the C# had the advantage of being compiled as 64-bit. I forgot to enable this in the C++ timing)

So I figure, I can write the majority of the code base in C# (Which C# makes very easy to write), and then write native versions of things where the performance is critical. The particular code piece I tested in C# and C++ was one of the critical areas where > 95% of processing time was spent.

What's the recommended wisdom on writing native code here though? I've never written a C# application that calls native C++, so I have no idea what to do. I want to do this in a way that minimizes the cost of having to do the native calls as much as possible.

Thanks!

Edit: Below is most of the code that I'm actually trying to work on. It's for a n-body simulation. 95-99% of the CPU time will be spent in Body.Pairwise().

```
class Body
{
    public double Mass;
    public Vector Position;
    public Vector Velocity;
    public Vector Acceleration;

    // snip

    public void Pairwise(Body b)
    {
        Vector dr = b.Position - this.Position;
        double r2 = dr.LengthSq();
        double r3i = 1 / (r2 * Math.Sqrt(r2));

        Vector da = r3i * dr;
        this.Acceleration += (b.Mass * da);
        b.Acceleration -= (this.Mass * da);
    }

    public void Predict(double dt)
    {
        Velocity += (0.5 * dt) * Acceleration;
        Position += dt * Velocity;
    }

    public void Correct(double dt)
    {
        Velocity += (0.5 * dt) * Acceleration;
        Acceleration.Clear();
    }
}
```

I also have a class that just drives the simulation with the following methods:

```
    public static void Pairwise(Body[] b, int n)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
                b[i].Pairwise(b[j]);
    }

    public static void Predict(Body[] b, int n, double dt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            b[i].Predict(dt);
    }

    public static void Correct(Body[] b, int n, double dt)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            b[i].Correct(dt);
    }
```

The main loop looks just like:

```
for (int s = 0; s < steps; s++)
{
    Predict(bodies, n, dt);
    Pairwise(bodies, n);
    Correct(bodies, n, dt);
}
```

The above is just the bare minimum of a larger application I'm actually working on. There's some more things going on, but the most performance critical things occur in these three functions. I know the pairwise function is slow (It's n^2), and I do have other methods that are faster (Barnes-hutt for one, which is n log n) but that's beyond the scope of what I'm asking for in this question.

The C++ code is nearly identical:

```
struct Body
{
public:
    double Mass;
    Vector Position;
    Vector Velocity;
    Vector Acceleration;

    void Pairwise(Body &b)
    {
        Vector dr = b.Position - this->Position;
        double r2 = dr.LengthSq();
        double r3i = 1 / (r2 * sqrt(r2));

        Vector da = r3i * dr;
        this->Acceleration += (b.Mass * da);
        b.Acceleration -= (this->Mass * da);
    }

    void Predict(double dt)
    {
        Velocity += (0.5 * dt) * Acceleration;
        Position += dt * Velocity;
    }

    void Correct(double dt)
    {
        Velocity += (0.5 * dt) * Acceleration;
        Acceleration.Clear();
    }
};

void Pairwise(Body *b, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            b[i].Pairwise(b[j]);
}

void Predict(Body *b, int n, double dt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        b[i].Predict(dt);
}

void Correct(Body *b, int n, double dt)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        b[i].Correct(dt);
}
```

Main loop:

```
for (int s = 0; s < steps; s++)
{
    Predict(bodies, n, dt);
    Pairwise(bodies, n);
    Correct(bodies, n, dt);
}
```

There also exists a Vector class, that works just like a regular mathematical vector, which I'm not including for brevity.

Comment: C# shouldn't be slower. you can achieve faster code using unchecked blocks to avoid overflow checking and other stuff.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326269/is-c-really-slower-than-say-c

Comment: @Yochai: I already tried that, by wrapping all my arithmetic in unsafe blocks. It boils down to a few functions which do lots of floating point math, but I'm doing -a lot- of computation each second. Also, I'd like to know how to call C++ from C#, as I already do have some existing code that's written in C++. Some of the newer code I'd like to write isn't computation related and is easier to write in C# though.

Comment: @Yochai: I'm not so sure that unchecked code is faster than checked code. I've witnessed situations in which it's consistently marginally slower, though I admit I can't explain why.

Comment: @Mike Bantegui, this is an old question, but you should check out C++ AMP for your N Body simulation. It can give an even better performance boost by letting run it on GPU hardware. Should be simple since you are already calling unmanaged code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to interface to the native code.  You could put it in a DLL and pinvoke.  Okay when you don't transition very often and the interface is thin.  The most flexible and speediest solution is to write a ref class wrapper in the C++/CLI language.  Have a look at [this magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163852.aspx) for an introduction.

Last but not least, you really ought to profile the C# code.  A factor of 8 is quite excessive.  Don't get started on this until you at least have half an idea why it is *that* slow.  You don't want to repro the cause in the C++ code, that would ruin a week of work.

And beware of the wrong instincts.  64-bit code is *not* actually faster, it is usually a bit slower than x86 code.  It's got a bunch of extra registers which is *very* nice.  But all the pointers are double the size and you don't get double the cpu cache.
.

Comment: I redid the timings, making sure the input data was identical, and it's still 5x slower. Are there any things I should watch out for that could easily sap performance in C#?

Comment: Almost doubling the performance by simply redoing the timings would be a Red Flag in my book. There's no generic play-book for optimizing C# code, only good profilers that show you where the cycles go.  Obvious mistakes are profiling the Debug build or with the debugger attached.

Comment: I think the "twice as fast" came from the fact that I ran through visual studio. I can consistently get timings of 500 ms (C#) and 2000 ms (C++) for a tiny computation. I did profile and did confirm the one method where all of the cycles were spent, which was identical in both platforms and had the same percentage of CPU time (99%).

Comment: @Mike Bantegui: Hans is right. You gotta find out what's *really* going on. Of course, when I hear "where the cycles go", and "where all of the cycles were spent" I'm immediately suspicious, because all too often the biggest time wasters are innocent-looking or even invisible function calls, which disguise themselves by causing the time to be spent elsewhere. I would encourage you to get down and dirty - step it at the instruction level, or do [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).

Answer (score 3):

You have two choices:  P/Invoking and C++/CLI.

**P/Invoking**

By using P/Invoke, or Platform Invoke, it is possible for .NET (and therefore C#) to call into unmanaged code (your C++ code).  It can be a bit overwhelming, but it is definitely possible to have your C# code call into performance critical C++ code.

Some MSDN links to get you started:

- [Consuming Unmanaged DLL Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26thfadc.aspx)
- [Interop Marshaling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eaw10et3.aspx)
- [DllImportAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx)

Basically, you will create a C++ DLL that has defined all the unmanaged functions you want to call from C#.  Then, in C# you will use the `DllImportAttribute` to import that function into C#.

For instance, you have a C++ project that creates a Monkey.dll with the following function:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void FastMonkey();
```

You will then have a definition in C# as follows:

```
class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("Monkey.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.CDecl)]
    public static extern void FastMonkey();
}
```

You can then call the C++ function in C# by calling `NativeMethods.FastMonkey`.

Few common gotchas and notes:

- Spend time learning Interop Marshaling.  Understanding this will greatly help creating proper P/Invoking definitions.
- The default calling convention is StdCall, but C++ will default to CDecl.
- The default character set is ANSI, so if you want to marshal Unicode strings, you will have to update your `DllImport` definition (see [MSDN - DllImport.CharSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset.aspx) documentation).
- http://www.pinvoke.net/ is a useful resource for knowing how to P/Invoke standard Windows functions call.  You can also use that for a clue how to marshal something if you know of a Windows function call that is similar.

**C++/CLI**

C++/CLI is a series of extensions to C++ created by Microsoft to create .NET assemblies with C++.  C++/CLI also allows you to mix unmanaged and managed code together into a "mixed" assembly.  You can create a C++/CLI assembly that contains both your performance critical code and any .NET class wrapper around it you want.

For more information with C++/CLI, I recommended starting with [MSDN - Language Features for Targeting the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw.aspx) and [MSDN - Native and .NET Interoperability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbz07712.aspx).

I recommend you start with the P/Invoking route.  I have found having a clear separation between unmanaged and managed code helps to simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, is Vector a class or struct?  I suspect it's a class, and Arthur Stankevich hit the nail on the head with his observation that you may be allocating many of these. Try making Vector a struct, or reusing the same Vector objects.

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering the same thing. I've seen many times that a Vector type is implemented in the Java way, which cause a lot of allocations. While in C++ the Vector's operations can be mostly inlined. To achieve compariable performance to C++, Vector type should be implemented as struct, and prefer to pass as ref parameter for operations instead of using overloaded operators, so that it can be better inlined by jitter.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is create C++ ActiveX dlls.

Then you can reference them in the C# project, Visual Studio will create interops that will wrap the ActiveX COM Object.

You can use the interop Code like C# code, no additional wrapping code.

More about AciveX/ C#:

[Create and Use a C++ ActiveX component within a .NET environment](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/ActiveXNet.aspx)

Comment: Is this the most efficient way to this? Or would the P/Invoke more efficient? I don't mind one way being harder, as long as it means I can extract as much performance as possible.

Comment: It's easy to do. I don't think there's a difference in communication overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> "I did some benchmarking on two
>   different implementations of some code
>   (One in C#, another in C++) and the
>   timings showed that the C++ version
>   was 8 times faster"

I did some numerical calculation in C#, C++, Java and a bit of F# and the biggest diffrence between C# and C++ was 3.5.

Profile your C# version and find the bottleneck (maybe there are some IO - related problems, unnecessary allocation)

Comment: There is no IO bottleneck (no actual IO beyond loading the test data), I re-checked the code and I can confirm that there's one method (on both C# and C++) that does nothing but raw computation, and it takes up 99% of the time.

Comment: Sure, I can post the particular parts that are known to be expensive. It's nothing more than a gravity simulation. Give me a few minutes and I'll update my main post.

Answer (score 0):

P/Invoke is definitely easier than COM Interop for the simple case. However, if you do bigger chunks of a class model in C++, you might really want to consider C++/CLI or COM Interop.

ATL makes you whip up a class in no time, and once the object is instantiated, the invocation overhead is basically as small as with P/Invoke (unless you use dynamic dispatch, IDispatch, but that should be obvious).

Of course, C++/CLI is the very best option there, but that's not going to work everywhere. P/Invoke can be made to work everywhere. COM interop is [supported on Mono up to degree](http://www.mono-project.com/COM_Interop)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing a lot of implicit Vector class allocations in your code:

```
Vector dr = b.Position - this.Position;
...
Vector da = r3i * dr;
this.Acceleration += (b.Mass * da);
b.Acceleration -= (this.Mass * da);
```

Try reusing already allocated memory.