# .Net vs C++ (performance)

Tags: c#, c++, .net

How much of a performance penalty are you paying when going to .Net from a vanilla c++ unmanaged environment. I have heard that the difference is smaller now than what it used to be?

I am referring to a PC environment and not embedded systems

Comment: Somthing like this: [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c)?

Comment: Interesting. I actually didn't consider that it in some cases can be faster...

Comment: the main difference is in the time it takes you to do your program

Comment: Could be anything, from a performance gain to orders of magnitude loss, depending on task.

Comment: In my case it's a moot point since I work in Asp.Net most of the time. Any microscopical difference will be insignificant compared to the web requests anyway :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is C# really slower than say C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326269/is-c-sharp-really-slower-than-say-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's absolutely depends on your project.

But remember itat `.Net` is not designed for high performance computing, but for high productivity.

So, in cases on stressing performance it will *almost* always loose in front of `c`, `c++` or say `python`.  But if you measure time you need deliver a simple windows based application, full of modern features,, the story *almost* always will be inverse.

Comment: Huh? Python is extremely slow.

Comment: is python good for high performance computing ?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer, it depends on what you are doing. There are several places to read about this.

[C++ performance vs. Java/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145110/c-performance-vs-java-c)

[Head-to-head benchmark: C++ vs .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/212856/Head-to-head-benchmark-Csharp-vs-NET)

[C# versus C++ versus Java performance comparison](http://reverseblade.blogspot.com/2009/02/c-versus-c-versus-java-performance.html)

Comment: Great point made in the article "Engineers are expensive and servers are not!"